# Hibernate mappedBy reference an unknown target entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, mapping

I have several entity classes created dynamically from db, however when I annotate them with relationships I have following error

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:         coma.entity.impl.CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl.competence in coma.entity.impl.CompetenceEntityImpl.competenceCriteriaEntityImpl] with root cause
```

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: coma.entity.impl.CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl.competence in coma.entity.impl.CompetenceEntityImpl.competenceCriteriaEntityImpl

My entity classes are as follows

```
package coma.entity.impl;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import coma.entity.CompetenceEntity;
import coma.exception.InvalidIDException;


@Entity
@Table(name = "competence")
public class CompetenceEntityImpl implements CompetenceEntity, Serializable {
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "competence", targetEntity = JobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl.class)
public Set<JobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl> jobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "competence",targetEntity = CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl.class)
public Set<CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl> competenceCriteriaEntityImpl;
/**
 * 
 */



/**
 * Identifier of competence
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_competence")
private int idCompetence;



public Set<JobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl> getJobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl() {
    return jobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl;
}

public void setJobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl(Set<JobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl> jobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl) {
    this.jobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl = jobProfileCompetenceEntityImpl;
}

public Set<CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl> getCompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl() {
    return competenceCriteriaEntityImpl;
}

public void setCompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl(Set<CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl> competenceCriteriaEntityImpl) {
    this.competenceCriteriaEntityImpl = competenceCriteriaEntityImpl;
}

public void setIdCompetence(int idCompetence) {
    this.idCompetence = idCompetence;
}

/**
 * Name of competence
 */
@Column(name = "name_competence")
private String nameCompetence;

/**
 * Identifier category competence
 */
@Column(name = "id_category_competence_enum")
private int idCategoryCompetenceEnum;

/**
 * Constructor without parameters
 */
public CompetenceEntityImpl() {

}

/**
 * Constructor with parameters
 * 
 * @param idCompetence
 * @param nameCompetence
 * @param idCategoryCompetenceEnum
 */
public CompetenceEntityImpl(int idCompetence, String nameCompetence, int idCategoryCompetenceEnum) {
    this.idCompetence = idCompetence;
    this.nameCompetence = nameCompetence;
    this.idCategoryCompetenceEnum = idCategoryCompetenceEnum;
}

/**
 * Return identifier of current competence
 * 
 * @return idCompetence
 */
@Override
public int getIdCompetence() {
    return idCompetence;
}

/**
 * Return name of current competence
 * 
 * @return nameCompetence
 */
@Override
public String getNameCompetence() {
    return nameCompetence;
}

/**
 * Set name of current competence
 * 
 * @param nameCompetence
 */
@Override
public void setNameCompetence(String nameCompetence) {
    this.nameCompetence = nameCompetence;
}

/**
 * Return identifier category competence
 * 
 * @return idCategoryCompetence
 */
@Override
public int getIdCategoryCompetenceEnum() {
    return idCategoryCompetenceEnum;
}

/**
 * Set identifier category competence
 * 
 * @param idCategoryCompetenceEnum
 */
@Override
public void setIdCategoryCompetenceEnum(int idCategoryCompetenceEnum) throws InvalidIDException {
    if (idCategoryCompetenceEnum < 0) {
        throw new InvalidIDException("The idCategoryCompetenceEnum must be greater than 0");
    } else {
        this.idCategoryCompetenceEnum = idCategoryCompetenceEnum;
    }

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + idCategoryCompetenceEnum;
    result = prime * result + idCompetence;
    result = prime * result + ((nameCompetence == null) ? 0 : nameCompetence.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    CompetenceEntityImpl other = (CompetenceEntityImpl) obj;
    if (idCategoryCompetenceEnum != other.idCategoryCompetenceEnum)
        return false;
    if (idCompetence != other.idCompetence)
        return false;
    if (nameCompetence == null) {
        if (other.nameCompetence != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nameCompetence.equals(other.nameCompetence))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CompetenceEntityImpl [idCompetence=" + idCompetence + ", nameCompetence=" + nameCompetence
            + ", idCategoryCompetenceEnum=" + idCategoryCompetenceEnum + "]";
}

}
```

and

```
package coma.entity.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import coma.entity.CompetenceCriteriaEntity;
import coma.exception.InvalidIDException;

@Entity
@Table(name = "competence_criteria")
public class CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl implements    CompetenceCriteriaEntity, Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id_competence_criteria")
private int idCompetenceCriteria;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CompetenceEntityImpl.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_competence")
CompetenceEntityImpl competenceEntityImpl;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CriteriaEntityImpl.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_criteria")
CriteriaEntityImpl criteriaEntityImpl;

@Column(name = "id_criteria", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int idCriteria;

@Column(name = "id_competence", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int idCompetence;



public CompetenceEntityImpl getCompetenceEntityImpl() {
    return competenceEntityImpl;
}


public void setCompetenceEntityImpl(CompetenceEntityImpl competenceEntityImpl) {
    this.competenceEntityImpl = competenceEntityImpl;
}


public CriteriaEntityImpl getCriteriaEntityImpl() {
    return criteriaEntityImpl;
}


public void setCriteriaEntityImpl(CriteriaEntityImpl criteriaEntityImpl) {
    this.criteriaEntityImpl = criteriaEntityImpl;
}


public CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl() {
}


public CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl(int idCompetenceCriteria, int idCompetence, int idCriteria) {
    this.idCompetenceCriteria = idCompetenceCriteria;
    this.idCompetence = idCompetence;
    this.idCriteria = idCriteria;
}



@Override
public int getIdCompetenceCriteria() {
    return idCompetenceCriteria;
}

@Override
public void setIdCompetenceCriteria(int idCompetenceCriteria) {
    this.idCompetenceCriteria = idCompetenceCriteria;
}

@Override
public int getIdCompetence() {
    return idCompetence;
}

@Override
public void setIdCompetence(int idCompetence) throws InvalidIDException {
    if (idCompetence < 0) {
        throw new InvalidIDException("The idCompetence must be greater than 0");
    } else {
        this.idCompetence = idCompetence;
    }
}

@Override
public int getIdCriteria() {
    return idCriteria;
}

@Override
public void setIdCriteria(int idCriteria) throws InvalidIDException {
    if (idCriteria < 0) {
        throw new InvalidIDException("The idCriteria must be greater than 0");
    } else {
        this.idCriteria = idCriteria;
    }

}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + idCompetence;
    result = prime * result + idCompetenceCriteria;
    result = prime * result + idCriteria;
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl other = (CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl) obj;
    if (idCompetence != other.idCompetence)
        return false;
    if (idCompetenceCriteria != other.idCompetenceCriteria)
        return false;
    if (idCriteria != other.idCriteria)
        return false;
    return true;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl [idCompetenceCriteria=" + idCompetenceCriteria + ", idCompetence="
            + idCompetence + ", idCriteria=" + idCriteria + "]";
}


}
```

I am getting really confused and desperate of Hibernate...

Comment: as the message says your "mappedBy" value is wrong. It should be the name of the FIELD/PROPERTY on the other side of the BIDIRECTIONAL relation, that links back to this class. e.g CompetenceEntityImpl.competenceCriteriaEntityImpl claims to link back via field CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl.competence, yet that doesn't exist. Instead mappedBy should be "competenceEntityImpl". This would be found in any basic JPA docs

Comment: Thanks, that resolved my issue

Comment: added as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

As the message says your "*mappedBy*" value is wrong. It should be the name of the FIELD/PROPERTY on the other side of the BIDIRECTIONAL relation, that links back to this class. e.g `CompetenceEntityImpl.competenceCriteriaEntityImpl` claims to link back via field `CompetenceCriteriaEntityImpl.competence`, yet that doesn't exist. Instead *mappedBy* should be "`competenceEntityImpl`". This would be found in any basic JPA docs